# Single Backslash to double backslash Conversion

Tags: javascript, string, replace, str-replace

I want all single backslashes to be converted into double backslash

`"C:\Users\MyName\ringtone.mp3"` --> `"C:\\Users\\MyName\\ringtone.mp3"`

But for some reason it returns `"C:UsersMyNameingtone.mp3"`

So far I have tried the escape() function and the encodeURI() function but they don't work either. Partial of the string comes from nodejs OS Module which only returns with a single backslash on windows (homedir() function). 
Here is what I have so far in the function

```
function normalize(path: string): string {
   return path.normalize().replace(/\\/g, '\\');
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: replace by "\\\\" instead of "\\", Reason:- because "\" is a escape character so "\\" is interpreted as `\" so you need "\\\\" to have "\\"

Comment: I just tested `os.homedir()` and it correctly has slashes.  can you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your nodejs script so we can see how you are using the value?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```js
var original = 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\ringtone.mp3';
var replaced = original.normalize().replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');

console.log('Original: ' + original);
console.log('Replaced: ' + replaced);
```

From what I see you had 2 problems:

First, it seems you were initializing your string like this:

```
var original = 'C:\Users\MyName\ringtone.mp3'
```

This would make your actual string value `C:UsersMyNameingtone.mp3` because a `\` character in javascript symbolizes an escape character.

Second, is because the `\` character is an escape character, so the `'\\'` in your replace function is only looking to replace the matching pattern with a single backslash.

Comment: An explanation about _why_ this works would be nice.

Comment: Thats the problem, the input string comes from the machine(nodejs OS module) itself not the user which is creating the problem.

Comment: if your input string is garbage (aka doesn't have actual slash characters) then there is nothing you can do.  you can't replace a slash that isn't there.